# How do I save a file object to a shelve file?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, object, shelve

When I run the following code:

```
import shelve

input = open("input.txt",)
shelveFile = shelve.open("myData")
shelveFile["inputFile"] = input
input.close()
shelveFile.close()
```

I expect the shelve file `myData` to hold the file object `input`. Instead, running the code produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ashutoshmishra/Documents/Sandbox/Sandbox3.py", line 5, in <module>
    shelveFile["inputFile"] = input
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/shelve.py", line 124, in __setitem__
    p.dump(value)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

I was wondering why I could not save the file object `input` to the shelve file `myData`?

Comment: Read the file: `shelveFile["inputFile"] = input.read()`

Comment: @DanD. thanks, this fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is taken from @DanD.'s comment above.

> Read the file: `shelveFile["inputFile"] = input.read()`